# VBA to filter value in two colums and to delete rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm working on a sub() to import a .csv that i receive monthly (it's my very first macro).
The structure of the file is very easy: there are 5 columns and a variable number of rows.

In columns A there are dates (dd/mm/yyyy), in B codes, in C names, in D and E statistics (numbers).
In the first row I have created a row with titles.
Here the code:

```
Sub ImportCSV()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\File.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Name = "FileName"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(1, 1) = "DATE"
    Cells(1, 2) = "CODE"
    Cells(1, 3) = "NAME"
    Cells(1, 4) = "STATS1"
    Cells(1, 5) = "STATS2"
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Columns("D").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Columns("D").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Columns("E").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Columns("E").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

Now, I would like to clean these sheet with a filter that:

- can select the last day of the previous month from column A (usually
  I receive the file during the firs days of the current month. In
  column A could be also dates of the current month so I can't select 
  the last day...alternatively, I was thinking about an inputbox) and
  then delete all the other dates; **in this column I have dates repeated**
- then, the filter is on column C and should apply 3 different filter:

  1. cells in column C **with the word "x"** and then delete these rows;
  2. cells in column C **with the word "y"** and then delete these rows;
  3. cells in column C **without the word "z"** and then delete these rows;

Hope that everything is clear...

Comment: What type of data are we talking about in column C. Just single words?

Comment: It's a string like "Name XWord Word" or "Word Y Word"

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can work with and get some ideas from hopefully. I made an example with some sample data. It's a bit extensive (read: It can be made more compact), but I'm hoping you'll be able to understand what is going on like this.

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample code:</sub>***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filtering()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Retrieve the last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Set your range object where you want to apply a filter
    Set rng = .Range("A1:E" & lr)

    With rng

        'Apply first two filters in one go
        .AutoFilter 3, Array("*X*", "*Y*"), xlFilterValues

        'Test for visible rows and if so, delete them
        If .SpecialCells(12).Count > 5 Then .Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1, 5).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

        'Apply second filter
        .AutoFilter 3, "<>*Z*", xlFilterValues

        'Test for visible rows and if so, delete them
        If .SpecialCells(12).Count > 5 Then .Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1, 5).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

        'Remove filter
        .AutoFilter

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JvdV! I've understood the logic of the first part. I don't understand `If .SpecialCells(12).Count > 5 Then .Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1, 5).Rows.EntireRow.Delete` and I don't see the first filter for the date (e.g.31/10/2019)

Comment: A short breakdown: `.SpecialCells(12).Count` will count all visible cells first to ensure we won't get an error in the occasion where you would have zero hits. Then the `.Offset(1).Resize(lr-1,5)` will get a new range object underneath your header row. The `5` specifically is there because you talking about a 5 column range.